Cannot access offset of type string on string (0) PHP - Swagger error
I am building web app using PHP and I got this error from swagger when making auth for login to my app.

Cannot access offset of type string on string (0).

Here is the code for the route:
  /**
     * @OA\Post(
     *      path="/auth/login",
     *      tags={"auth"},
     *      summary="Login to system using email and password",
     *      @OA\Response(
     *           response=200,
     *           description="User data and JWT"
     *      ),
     *      @OA\RequestBody(
     *          description="Credentials",
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              required={"email","pwd"},
     *              @OA\Property(property="email", type="string", example="example@example.com", description="User email address"),
     *              @OA\Property(property="pwd", type="string", example="some_password", description="User password")
     *          )
     *      )
     * )
     */
    Flight::route('POST /login', function() {
        $payload = Flight::request()->data->getData();
        var_dump($payload);

        $user = Flight::get('auth_service')->get_user_by_email($payload['email']);
        var_dump($user);



        if(!$user || !password_verify($payload['pwd'], $user['pwd']))
            Flight::halt(500, "Invalid username or password");

        unset($user['pwd']);
    });

I have double checked all methods in service and dao but can't find the solution.
Tried var_dump() but got same error when using it.

Which line is getting that error?

if $user isn't an array, $user['pwd'] can't be used.

The error suggests that either $user or $payload is a string, not an array.

if(!$user || !password_verify($payload['pwd'], $user['pwd'])) here is the error - $user['pwd']

As I said, you'll get that error if either of those variables is a string. ['pwd'] requires it to be an array.

Thank you. Could you suggest how to try to debug it? I'm new to PHP

The var_dump() lines should tell you which. It will say something like (string) "..." instead of Array(size) ...

Check your get_user_by_email() method to see why it might return a string instead of a user array.

The problem was in get_user_by_email() method.
The metod calls query_unique() method which was not good. I have fixed it and now it works.
